# Firebase adding node in Java Script

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a database structure like this:

```
|--1
|  |---'abc':1
|  |---'def':2
|--2
|  |---'efg':1
|  |---'ghi':2
```

Every time the user submits an entry in the web app, it is added with an entry_id one more than the last entry_id. How do I obtain the last entry_id present in the database structure?

Comment: Do you really need your entry_id's sequential? If not, let the Firebase generate unique entry_id's for you.

Comment: I come from SQL world, so there we use user_ids as primary keys. So I was thinking if that thing is possible here or not?

Comment: Making id's sequential will not help you in any case. Because if you delete some of data, for example when you delete entry 3, your id's will be like `1,2,4,5..`. So calculating the last id then incrementing it and using it is useless in that case. But if you want to make your id's unique so making them sequential is a method in SQL but in Firebase. Firebase generates unique id for you to make your work easy. If you need how to, then I will answer your question that way.